# How can I convert a json that contains array to javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have json like below,

```
{
    "Message": "{\"Errors\":[\"The message.\",\"The message.\"],\"Infos\":[\"The message.\"],\"Warnings\":[\"The message.\"],\"Successes\":[\"The message.\"]}"
}
```

I would like to convert it to an object like below,

```
var obj = {
    Errors : new Array(),
    Infos : new Array(),
    Warnings : new Array(),
    Successes : new Array()
}
```

**Note:** I cannot make changes on the json.

I used **jQuery.parseJson**, but I couldn't do.

Comment: It's because the json itself is invalid: copy-paste your string and go the the console, type JSON.parse(your string);

Comment: @frenchie I checked it by using http://jsonlint.com/. It was valid.

Comment: @frenchie: No, the JSON is perfectly valid. It's very *odd*, but it's valid.

Comment: It looks like the JSON is invalid. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YY3Co.png)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: It looks like it's invalid; see the pic of the string going through JSON.parse in my answer.

Comment: @frenchie: No, it's valid. You've just failed to include all of it, and failed to wrap it in a string correctly to pass it to `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've posted is unusual: It's JSON defining an object with a single property, `Message`, which has a string value containing a second embedded JSON string. Very odd structure.

If you're really receiving that as JSON, then:

```
var outer = jQuery.parseJSON(theStringWithTheJSON);
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(outer.Message);
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adutof/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/adutof/1/edit)

But if you're retrieving that via `ajax` (for instance), jQuery may well have already done the first `parseJSON` for you, in which case you just need to do the second bit:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    /* ...other parameters here...*/
    success: function(data) {
        var obj = jQuery.parseJson(data.Message);
    }
});
```

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adutof/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/adutof/2/edit)

But if you can, I would probably change the structure of the string you're receiving so it's not double-encoded like that:

```
{
    "Message": {
        "Errors": [
            "The message.",
            "The message."
        ],
        "Infos": [
            "The message."
        ],
        "Warnings": [
            "The message."
        ],
        "Successes": [
            "The message."
        ]
    }
}
```

Then you don't need to double-decode it, just the first decoding (which again may already be done for you, you haven't shown any code so it's hard to tell) is necessary and you can use `var obj = yourVariable.Message;`.

[Live Example](http://jsbin.com/adutof/3) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/adutof/3/edit)

Comment: Can not I do without make changes ? by using regex or otherwise ? All I know what you all said. So I coundn't do and I have asked this question. I have to do under this circumstances.

Comment: @sinanakyazici: I showed how to do it without making changes to it. That's exactly what the first part of the answer does.

Comment: @sinanakyazici: I've added live examples of all three options.